# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, dom

Here is the code:

```
let imagenes = document.querySelectorAll(".team");
let modal = document.querySelectorAll("#modal");
let img = document.querySelectorAll("#modal__img");
let boton = document.querySelectorAll("#modal__boton");

for (let i = 0; i < imagenes.length; i++){
  imagenes[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
    modal.classList.togle("modal--open");
  })
}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined    at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous>"
```

Comment: I suspect this snippet code doesn't reflect correctly with the error since `togle` is different from `toggle`. So please make sure you copy & paste the accurate snippet from your code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a `querySelectorAll`, you will get an HTML collection, therefore you will need to iterate through it's elements to toggle a class. It's faster to target by if you want to toggle only one element, but if you need to toggle more than one, your code would look something like this

```
const elements = document.quesySelectorAll('.myClass');
elements.forEach(x => x.classList.toggle('otherClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) with array-like data structure. Hence, `modal` is an array with no `classList` property. Use `document.getElementById`; it's faster anyways:

```
let modal = document.getElementById("#modal");
```